ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor not immediately picking up tasks when previous task exceeds period
I'm using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor in Java to execute tasks periodically using scheduleAtFixedRate(). However, I've noticed that when a task takes longer to execute than the specified period, the subsequent task is not immediately picked up by another thread.
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);

ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    System.out.println("Executing every 3 seconds with: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
    System.out.println("Executed with: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}, 1, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Output:
Executing every 3 seconds with: pool-1-thread-1
Executed with: pool-1-thread-1
Executing every 3 seconds with: pool-1-thread-1
Executed with: pool-1-thread-1
Executing every 3 seconds with: pool-1-thread-2
Executed with: pool-1-thread-2

In this code, I'm scheduling a task to execute every 3 seconds with an initial delay of 1 second. However, if the task execution takes longer than 3 seconds (of thread1), the subsequent task is not immediately picked up by another thread (thread2). Instead, it seems to wait until the current task completes, causing a delay in the execution of subsequent tasks.
Is this the expected behavior of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor? If so, is there a way to ensure that tasks are picked up immediately by available threads even if the previous task exceeds the specified period?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Yes this is expected behaviour. The javadoc says "If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute."
